# How to store values from PHP variables to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, leaflet

I am new to web technologies and I want to create a web app that allows a user to click on a map and a form will pop up and it will allow him to enter certain information. That information is saved on a database. Now I don't know how to pull that information because I need to create markers on the map with the longitude and latitude as its position. I don't know how to pass values from php variables to javascript

```
<?php
    require_once("mysqli_connect.php");

    $query = "SELECT * FROM markeri";

    $response = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

    if($response){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response)){
            $naziv = $row['naziv'];
            $opis = $row['opis'];
            $email = $row['email'];
            $latitude = $row['latitude'];
            $longitute = $row['longitute'];


        }
    }

?>
```

This is the code for pulling data from the database. Now I need to create markers on the map with all the information from the database.

```
var marker = L.marker(e.latlng);
marker.addTo(mymap).bindPopup(form).openPopup();

<div id="form">
    </br>
    Naziv:</br>
    <h1 id="naziv"></h1></br></br>
    Opis problema:</br>
    <p id="opis"></p> </textarea></br>
    E-mail:</br>
    <h3 id="email"> </h3></br></br>
</div>
```

I am using the Leaflet API for interaction with the map. I need to create markers by replacing e.latlng(which is a JS array) with latitude and longitude pulled from the database with PHP and to make a marker at that position. I need to fill the information in the "form" above as well for each individual marker.

This is the table in the database:
[image]

Comment: Using Ajax? After save, do AJAX request to PHP which will return JSON you need. And then just populate data into HTML.

Comment: @MykolaBorysyuk How would you do that ? I don't know how to store the information that I looped through.

Comment: On a curious note, why is this question voted down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have Jquery just do
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "some.php"
})
.success(function(res) {
    //If all ok you will get Object as a responce
    console.log(JSON.parse(res));
});
```

Insode you some.php script 
`$data is object that you need`.

`echo json_encode($data);`

Now just in success handler. Loop and add elements into table, div,whatever using JQuery or pure JavaScript.

Looks like this.
http://api.jquery.com/append/

`$( "p" ).append( "<strong>Hello</strong>" );`

You may want to check other methods. This is just example.

Hope this helps.